# Magento 1.x API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2, integration

In an integration with Magento 1.x SOAP v2 API through WSDL I've encontered many agencies with different Magento versions and WSDL files.
The worst case scenario is when the "communication interface" changes from what an already imported WSDL file from what a new WSDL file has.

Like from "Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortType" to "PortType".

Somebody faced this in Delphi or another language with an WSDL importer?